# How do I find a breaker that runs a circuit when that circuit is dead?

Tags: wiring

I have 3 plugs and one light fixture that stopped working. I have tested all breakers in the box and they are good and sending power, but I don't know which breaker runs the dead circuit. I have also tested the wires going to each plug and light, those wires are dead.

Comment: You didn't indicate what room the outlets were in. Including that information can be helpful. The non-working outlets may be powered through a GFCI.  GfCI outlets can be in odd places, like the garage.

Comment: It is important to indicate in what room are the outlets located.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this forum thing, the outlets are the living room, and this home is an older one, built in the '60s.

Comment: Try switching all the breakers off, then on. Some don't move very far when they trip, so they may "look like" they are on, when they are not.

Comment: @RMDman my house has a GFCI outlet that controls (protects?) the garage outlets...and it's located in the basement bathroom *closet*, LOL.

Comment: @Huesmann, yep...been there, done that looking in odd places for GFCIs.

Comment: All breakers work, I tested them with a multi-meter, and this home has no gfci outlets.

Answer (score 5):

The other solution may be to get a circuit tracer whose transmitter can be powered by a battery, such as the Greenlee "Power Finders". These essentially put a radio signal onto the wire so it acts as a broadcasting antenna, and use a short-range receiver to let you track the wire through the wall. I successfully used one of these to find the place where a contractor had accidentally cut through a circuit, after then contractor's own electrician tried to claim that it wasn't their fault.

The plus is that these can let you follow the signal to *exactly* where the break occurred, without having to go by trial and error. (At least for NMC; I suspect it would have trouble working through conduit but haven't tried it.)

The minus is cost. These are professional tools and priced accordingly. Not usually cheap even used on eBay.

Comment: I need to investigate how well they'd work for finding breaks in XLR cables.

Comment: If it's dead you can just use a signal tracer, +1. Why with the XLR though? You make your own cables? Can't you still take them to GC and get free ones or was that always bs?

Comment: Secondhand 20yo equipment, nonprofit budget.

Answer (score 4):

First, switch off the main house breaker, so that you don't have any power in the house. Then open the affected boxes and see if any wires are broken, or disconnected. Outlets are cheap enough that it might be worth it replacing them, just in case.

If this does not solve the problem, you can find the breaker controlling the affected outlets by a process of elimination. Get a helper, and plug a lamp to an outlet. Flip breakers one by one until the helper yells at you that the lamp light went off. If you don't have a helper, you can use a loud tool or speaker, or get a tool like the Klein Tools ET310 AC Circuit Breaker Finder.

Once you have mapped all working outlets in the house to their breakers, try to infer how are the bad outlet connected to the line that goes to the breaker. For example, if the outlets are part of a series of outlets in a room, figure out which is the last working outlet in that run just before the ones that stopped working. Bu looking into the affected outlets, you can get clues about where the wire is coming from. You'll probably find a broken splice inside of the last connected box in the series.

If the outlets are in a garage, outdoors, kitchen or bathroom, check if one is a GFCI and press the reset button. Sometimes GFCI outlets are wired in series and a fault in one turns off the whole series.

Since you mentioned that the run is part of both a fixture and outlets, I'll assume that you are dealing with an old house. This will make things harder.

From your comments:

> there may be a break in a junction box in the attic

If you can't find the breaker that's controlling the bad outlets: Did this happen all of the sudden, or did it happen as you were plugging something in and giggled the outlet? Look for a loose connection in that outlet before you climb into the attic.

Comment: Guessing and electricity don't go well together.  Seeing that three outlets and a light is off, might just be faster to turn off the main/or all the breakers and check those outlets.

Comment: I didn't say to guess and poke your finger inside. I'm trying to tell the OP how to figure out the line to which the broken outlet belongs, so that he can then check the box. The OP can test for power before opening boxes, as he has indicated.

Comment: Even if the outlets aren't garage/outdoors/k/b, look around for a gfci (outdoors, garage, kitchen, bath)... sometimes people wire things very strangely.

Comment: If you don't have a helper, plug a boombox/vacuum/blender/compressor into the outlet so that you can hear it from the breaker.

Comment: this is an old home, most likely built in the '60s. i cant plug a lamp or radio in to the outlets because the circuit is dead. The outlets are not run in a series either . i'm thinking there may be a break in a junction box in the attic , not sure, what is you guys opinion on that, and also could tone tracer help me find the right breaker for this circuit? Also there are no gfci outlets in the house.

Comment: I meant to plug the lamp on the circuits that work, so that you can get an idea of which breaker is most likely controlling the dead ones. But old houses have that problem, that people just branched off any available wire behind a wall.

Comment: I have flipped all the breakers but still got nothing that worked or matched that circuit.

Comment: I'd investigate each of the impacted boxes for any sign of power within the box before proceeding to look for it elsewhere.  If a box has power within, the fault is probably there.  Also by looking inside each of these four boxes you should be able to see which one is first in the chain, which will make this answer's search a lot more effective.

Comment: I have already tested each outlet and the light fixture, there is no power, each outlet is dead, wire to the outlets are  also dead, but all wires coming out of each breaker is live. There is no series with these outlets and fixture each outlet has only two wires feeding it.